# How to join two values to print in one line using jq

Tags: json, github, jq

I have this list that prints out using the *gh api* command:

```
    [
  {
    "login": "anthonyd-cd",
    "id": 35614549,
    "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjM1NjE0NTQ5",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/35614549?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/anthonyd-cd",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/anthonyd-cd",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/anthonyd-cd/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/anthonyd-cd/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/anthonyd-cd/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/anthonyd-cd/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/anthonyd-cd/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/anthonyd-cd/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/anthonyd-cd/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/anthonyd-cd/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/anthonyd-cd/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false,
    "contributions": 5
  },
  {
    "login": "elJoeyJojo",
    "id": 17091968,
    "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE3MDkxOTY4",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/17091968?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/elJoeyJojo",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/elJoeyJojo",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/elJoeyJojo/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/elJoeyJojo/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/elJoeyJojo/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/elJoeyJojo/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/elJoeyJojo/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/elJoeyJojo/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/elJoeyJojo/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/elJoeyJojo/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/elJoeyJojo/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false,
    "contributions": 2
  }
]
```

I am trying to use *jq* to print out only the *login* and *contributions* field but into one line like so:

***gh api repos/eljoeyjojo/diner-app/contributors | jq -r '.[].login, .[].contributions'***

Expected Result

```
anthony-cd 5
eljoeyjojo 2
```

Actual Result

```
anthony-cd
eljoeyjojo
5
2
```

Any idea how I could print/merge these two fields? Would I have to use a for loop in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using the iterator `.[]` twice, so each field is extracted from a different iteration. Pull the iterator up front and extract from the context of an iteration step. Then you can use various methods to combine those, one being string interpolation `"\(...)"`.

```bash
jq -r '.[] | "\(.login) \(.contributions)"'
```

```json
anthonyd-cd 5
elJoeyJojo 2
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_KNhzy8b2kG)